# How Winter-Hardy are Austral Gem Ferns and Kangaroo Paw Ferns?

Tags: ferns, plant-hardiness

I looked up online cold hardiness of austral gem ferns and kangaroo paw ferns but only got contradictory results. Some sources say they are cold-hardy in zone 10 and above, yet others say they cannot withstand temperatures below 50°F(10°C). So I wonder which information is right. How cold-hardy are these two ferns?